# Why does this Outlook filter apply to the wrong e-mails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an Outlook filter implemented, which should move all emails from "foo@example.com" into the folder Foo. However, this filter also moves e-mails from "bar@example.com" and "baz@example.com" into the folder "Foo".

Attached is a screenshot of the rule:

[image: Outlook Rule]

This is also the only rule in Outlook, so I am certain no other rule is accidentally moving "bar@example.com" and "baz@example.com" into this folder either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons I can think of:

1. In order to confirm whether the problem is related to the Outlook rule, what if you disable or remove all your Outlook rules? Please check if the strange move operation will still continue.
2. If you re-create this Outlook rule and select other email addresses and email folders to test, will the issue continues or changes?
3. As I know, Outlook VBA scripts can also realize the automatic movement of email messages, please check if you have enable any VBA scripts in your Outlook client.
4. There could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.
5. A corrupted profile can lead this issue, so please try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if the issue could be resolved.

Update：

[image]

Comment: If I disable the rule, it no longer applies and no emails are moved. When I try it with other addresses, it works as expected - it's only "foo@example.com", which then *also* moves "bar@example.com" and "baz@examle.com". It should be noted that these addresses are not assigned to a natural person, but instead to services generating automated e-mails. I have no VBA scripts or Add-Ins. I recreated my Outlook profile, no change.

Comment: Have not got much clue yet. The issue seems to be more related to this particular service email account. Have you checked if there is any special connections between these three email address? Since I do not have the same special environment as you, I cannot reproduce this issue in my Outlook.

By the way, as a workaround, maybe you could try to modify your Outlook rule conditions as "with specific words in the message header" to make the outlook rule filtering more accurate.

Comment: Open an email message from "foo@example.com" and select the complete From attribute from its message header to improve the accuracy of filtering, as the screen added in the post above.